# Get XML elements only if they explicitly define any default namespace with Python and XPath

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, xml-namespaces

I'm parsing an XML string with Python and I'm looking for a XPath expression to retrieve only the elements that explicitly define any default namespace (xmlns, without prefixes).

I'm working with this example:

```
from lxml import etree

xml = '''
<TELCAL_DATAMANAGER_BDNT_1
    xmlns="urn:schemas-cosylab-com:BulkDataNTReceiver:1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-cosylab-com:BulkDataNTReceiver:1.0 BulkDataNTReceiver.xsd">
    <ReceiverStream Name="InterferometricStream1" participantPerStream="true">
        <ReceiverFlow Name="FullSpectralFlow" cbReceiveAvgProcessTimeoutSec="0.0018" multicastAddress="225.3.2.100"></ReceiverFlow>
        <ReceiverFlow Name="ChannelAveragesFlow" multicastAddress="225.3.2.200"></ReceiverFlow>
        <ReceiverFlow Name="WVRFlow" multicastAddress="225.3.2.30"></ReceiverFlow>
    </ReceiverStream>
    <ReceiverStream Name="InterferometricStream2" participantPerStream="true">
        <ReceiverFlow Name="FullSpectralFlow" cbReceiveAvgProcessTimeoutSec="0.0018" multicastAddress="225.3.2.100"></ReceiverFlow>
        <ReceiverFlow Name="ChannelAveragesFlow" multicastAddress="225.3.2.200"></ReceiverFlow>
        <ReceiverFlow Name="WVRFlow" multicastAddress="225.3.2.30"></ReceiverFlow>
    </ReceiverStream>
    <ReceiverStream Name="InterferometricStream3" participantPerStream="true">
        <ReceiverFlow Name="FullSpectralFlow" cbReceiveAvgProcessTimeoutSec="0.0018" multicastAddress="225.3.2.100"></ReceiverFlow>
        <ReceiverFlow Name="ChannelAveragesFlow" multicastAddress="225.3.2.200"></ReceiverFlow>
        <ReceiverFlow Name="WVRFlow" multicastAddress="225.3.2.30"></ReceiverFlow>
    </ReceiverStream>
</TELCAL_DATAMANAGER_BDNT_1>
'''

root = etree.fromstring(xml)

elements = root.xpath("//*[namespace-uri()!='' and not(local-name()='*')]")

for element in elements:
    print(element)
```

I get this result:

```
<Element {urn:schemas-cosylab-com:BulkDataNTReceiver:1.0}TELCAL_DATAMANAGER_BDNT_1 at 0x7f8100613640>
<Element {urn:schemas-cosylab-com:BulkDataNTReceiver:1.0}ReceiverStream at 0x7f80ffaaaf00>
<Element {urn:schemas-cosylab-com:BulkDataNTReceiver:1.0}ReceiverFlow at 0x7f80ffaaaf40>
<Element {urn:schemas-cosylab-com:BulkDataNTReceiver:1.0}ReceiverFlow at 0x7f80ffaaaec0>
<Element {urn:schemas-cosylab-com:BulkDataNTReceiver:1.0}ReceiverFlow at 0x7f80ffaaac80>
<Element {urn:schemas-cosylab-com:BulkDataNTReceiver:1.0}ReceiverStream at 0x7f80ffaaad40>
<Element {urn:schemas-cosylab-com:BulkDataNTReceiver:1.0}ReceiverFlow at 0x7f80ffaaac40>
<Element {urn:schemas-cosylab-com:BulkDataNTReceiver:1.0}ReceiverFlow at 0x7f80ffaaad80>
<Element {urn:schemas-cosylab-com:BulkDataNTReceiver:1.0}ReceiverFlow at 0x7f80ffaaacc0>
<Element {urn:schemas-cosylab-com:BulkDataNTReceiver:1.0}ReceiverStream at 0x7f80ffaaad00>
<Element {urn:schemas-cosylab-com:BulkDataNTReceiver:1.0}ReceiverFlow at 0x7f80ffaaadc0>
<Element {urn:schemas-cosylab-com:BulkDataNTReceiver:1.0}ReceiverFlow at 0x7f80ffaaab40>
<Element {urn:schemas-cosylab-com:BulkDataNTReceiver:1.0}ReceiverFlow at 0x7f80ffaaae00>
```

But I need only the `TELCAL_DATAMANAGER_BDNT_1` element, which is the only one with `xmlns="urn:schemas-cosylab-com:BulkDataNTReceiver:1.0"`

Expected result:

```
<Element {urn:schemas-cosylab-com:BulkDataNTReceiver:1.0}TELCAL_DATAMANAGER_BDNT_1 at 0x7f8100613640>
```

Is there an XPath expression to achieve this?

Comment: All elements are are in the scope of the default namespace. You can see it by trying `root.xpath("//*")`.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The rules for namespace declarations say they apply not just to the element where they appear, but to all descendant elements. You're trying to process the XML in a way that ignores the semantic rules for what it means.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath will return nodes where the namespace was declared not those that inherited it

```
//*[namespace-uri()!='' 
    and (namespace::*[name()=''] 
    and not(contains(name(), ':'))) 
    and namespace-uri() != namespace-uri(parent::* | ancestor::*)]
```

`not(contains(name(), ':'))` will filter out namespaces with prefix

```
from lxml import etree

xml = '''
<TELCAL_DATAMANAGER_BDNT_1 xmlns="urn:schemas-cosylab-com:BulkDataNTReceiver:1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-cosylab-com:BulkDataNTReceiver:1.0 BulkDataNTReceiver.xsd">
    <ReceiverStream Name="InterferometricStream1" participantPerStream="true">
      <ReceiverFlow Name="FullSpectralFlow" cbReceiveAvgProcessTimeoutSec="0.0018" multicastAddress="225.3.2.100"/>
      <ReceiverFlow Name="ChannelAveragesFlow" multicastAddress="225.3.2.200"/>
      <ReceiverFlow Name="WVRFlow" multicastAddress="225.3.2.30"/>
    </ReceiverStream>
    <ns1:ele xmlns:ns1="example.com">
      <ns1:el2>a</ns1:el2>
      <no_ns>b</no_ns>
      <no_ns1>
        <no_ns2>2</no_ns2>
      </no_ns1>
      <some xmlns="urn:schemas-cosylab-com:BulkDataNTReceiver:1.0">
        <other>o</other>
      </some>
      <no_ns3>d</no_ns3>
    </ns1:ele>
    <child xmlns="http://example.com/ns2">
        <grandchild xmlns="http://example.com/ns3"/>
    </child>
  </TELCAL_DATAMANAGER_BDNT_1>
'''

root = etree.fromstring(xml)

elements = root.xpath("//*[namespace-uri()!='' and (namespace::*[name()=''] and not(contains(name(), ':'))) and namespace-uri() != namespace-uri(parent::* | ancestor::*)]")

for element in elements:
    print(element)
```

Result

```
<Element {urn:schemas-cosylab-com:BulkDataNTReceiver:1.0}TELCAL_DATAMANAGER_BDNT_1 at 0x7f4580afa988>
<Element {http://example.com/ns2}child at 0x7f4580afa908>
<Element {http://example.com/ns3}grandchild at 0x7f4580afa8c8>
```

If `namespace-uri() != namespace-uri(parent::*)` is removed, all nodes with a default namespace will be returned.

**Note**: Found nodes are returned with their children that may or may not contain namespace declarations.

Comment: That XPath will fail to return a single element in e.g. `<root xmlns="http://example.com/ns1"><child xmlns="http://example.com/ns2"><grandchild xmlns="http://example.com/ns3"/></child></root>`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen OP requested elements where a default ns was declared so I added another node as example on my own interest to cover the use case. Besides, your example contains 3 different ns which should be returned I think.

Comment: your check `namespace-uri() = namespace-uri(child::*)` for the sample I showed in the comment means that your code fails to find any of those elements.

Comment: Will test your example and fix if possible.

Comment: @MartinHonnen updated the answer with a better working xpath that resolves your example.